# Rails 3: route.rb : how can i write match for /chart/demo/home

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In my rails application, I have a controller called demo which is stored at chart directory, I need to access a action called "home" in the demo controller, how should I need to write match in route.rb ?

match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
This is the only line what i have

site.com/chart/demo/home should call

app/controllers/chart/demo_controller.rb #action home

Thanks in advance,
Kannan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a namespace for the chart, if you've got many controllers that will function behind the 'chart directory.'

```
namespace :chart do
  match 'demo/home', :to => 'demo#home'
end
```

Then you've got to make sure that your demo controller indicates the namespace by changing:

```
class DemoController < ApplicationController
```

to

```
class Chart::DemoController < ApplicationController
```

and make sure that your demo controller is inside of a chart directory.
Then you can always check your routes using rake:routes in the console.